# Accurev Triggers for Security, Stream Management and JIRA Integration

Tags: perl, integration, jira, accurev, event-triggers

About 6 months ago we started using AccuRev with JIRA for our source control and issue management, but there are some obvious problems, like a lack of security, everyone can pretty much do anything, like lock and unlock stream and change streams belonging to anyone else and on top of it the default email trigger that ships with Accurev is not very good.

Accurev allows for pre-create, pre-keep, pre-promote and server-post-promote phase and I've decide to use those to help me manage some of the wild west of Accurev development. I'll stick with PERL since that is what they used for the original trigger and will post mine here later, but before I start, I was wondering if someone maybe already had this problem before, how did you solve it and if you could post some of your triggers here or ideas for triggers and what can be managed through them, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclosure, I've worked for AccuRev for almost 7 years.  It's mostly by design that AccuRev starts off in an open development model.  The goal is to enable whatever process you as an organization want to adopt.  Some companies flourish in this wide open model, others have very stringent requirements and lock things down tightly using a combination of GUI features and the triggers you mentioned.

The sample triggers we ship with the product provide a solid framework for advanced process security.  For example, one of the default clauses in the server_admin_trig.pl is that you can't change someone else's workspace.  Typically, companies will work with AccuRev at initial implementation time (or any time later, or on their own) to determine what level of customization, if any, is needed for these triggers.

Sounds like you have the requisite Perl experience to setup whatever you need, but can you give an example of some behavior you'd like to control, and perhaps I can post a sample.  As a sidebar, please feel free to contact me using my username @ accurev dot com and I'm sure we can find some way to assist.

Regards,
~James

Comment: For example, I'd like to allow promoting from workspace to an associated workstream without a ticket associated, but not allow to promote any further without having a ticket. The only place where the ticket presence is enforced by schema seems to be the workspace/stream boundary, the other don't seem to work so I wanted to solve this problem with a trigger. We need a code in a stream to be remotely built and tested, but don't want to require developers to use bogus issues for some throwaway or debug code.

Comment: Another thing is to enforce the locks on streams. It seems like anyone can really unlock a stream, so it looks like we need to have a trigger to enforce the locks.

Comment: Another case is we only want to restrict creation of streams and only allow to move streams around for users who reserved them, based on a stream name pattern. Also allow workspace to only be created under certain name pattern recognized streams.

Answer (score 0):

Since Accurev 5.7 there is a very good example server_admin_trigger.pl in the distribution with all the commands covered and described. Once we upgraded to 5.7, getting the admin trigger done just the way I wanted was a breeze.